# Unable to do insert/update (upsert) operations using PUT method with out using rest resource class in REST API

Tags: rest-api, rest, apexrest

i am trying to do insert and update operations using PUT method in REST API with out using rest resource class in workbench/postman. But i am getting following error as shown in image.

Can anybody answer my question why i am facing this problem. [image: This image for updaing]

[image: This is for inserting]

Note: Before answering to this, please go through PUT method in workbench or postman. If you go through workbench or postman, you may understand what my query is.

Thanking you
KS Kumar

Answer (score 1):

The standard REST API doesn't support the PUT method.

> Each resource in the Force.com REST API is identified by a named URI, and is accessed using standard HTTP methods (HEAD, GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE).

(Source: [Understanding Force.com REST Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_resources.htm))

Depending on what you are trying to achieve you can use POST or PATCH.

To create a new record then you can use POST. For example to create a new Account you can POST to `/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Account`

To update an existing record you can use PATCH. For example to update an existing Account you can PATCH to `/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Account/YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID`

Comment: Thank You @Alex Tennant.
But why salesforce specifically mentioned PUT Method?
When we can use PUT method?

Comment: @KSKumaar Where does Salesforce mention using the PUT method with the standard API, if you check the documentation for the two endpoints you've tried, neither mentions PUT https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_basic_info.htm https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_retrieve.htm

Comment: Hi @Alex Tennant,
Could you please check images which i uploaded. There you can find PUT method

Comment: @KSKumaar Salesforce gives you the PUT option in Workbench so you can call your own custom `@HttpPut` endpoints from Workbench.